# Pass DB name as variable in if exists statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query as below

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT * from @dbname.dbo.tbl1)
   BEGIN
   ...
   END
ELSE
   BEGIN
   ...
   END
```

Also The code in begin and end part for both if and else is large enough to use as a string for dynamic query. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use a try/except.

Comment: Alfons, I am not sure about try except, can you please explain in brief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
USE MASTER
DECLARE @dbname sysname
SET @dbname = 'MyDB'

IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM sysdatabases WHERE name = @dbname)
BEGIN
-- Action if true
END
ELSE
BEGIN
-- Action if False
END
```

In case you want to check for a specific table, as hinted in your question, you can modify as

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM sysobjects WHERE name = @dbname AND type = 'U')
```